# Check if two Location Instances are the same value?

Tags: android, geolocation, instance

I want to check if two location instances are the same value. I'm just not sure how to do this?

I get the first location by using a service to constantly check the location in the background. The second Location instance is declared within an activity and i use a `getAddress()` method to recieve the address from the location it found.

I thought maybe something like this might work but it didn't:

```
  // Initialization of First Location 
    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);
    Location FirstLocation =mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    //Initialization of Second Location
     Location SecondLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    //Checking if they are the same

    if (FirstLocation ==SecondLocation){
        System.out.println("It worked");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("It didn't work");
    }
```

It always returns "It didn't work".

Just wondering how I can solve this or if theres a better way?

Any feedback or answers would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to use `distanceTo()` method it returns the approximate distance in meters between to locations, something similar to  :

```
SecondLocation.distanceTo(FirstLocation) < 1;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank @B.M, for two things one for such a quick responce and two because it solved my problem! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Quick question, hope you don't mind? What does the '< 1' do?

Comment: if the `SecondLocation.distanceTo(FirstLocation) < 1; ` is true, means that the distance between `SecondLocation` and `FirstLocation` is inferior to 1 meter @magicmass

Answer (score 0):

the double equal is used for primitive types (integers , doubles, ...) for objects use the `equals()` method so you will have `if (FirstLocation.equals(SecondLocation))`